# Connecting to existing database to make ASP tables

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am taking a hand in development for the first time and trying to teach myself some things,  and chose to start with ASP and Visual Studio. I have a rather simple question to ask... I generally search and search and search... but I don't know what the proper term/phrase is for what I'm searching for.

Assumptions: Visual Studio 2013 (not express), asp.net mvc5 with bootstrap(3.1.1) is what I'll be using.

Two part question:  what is the phrase/term to use when searching for an answer to part two? data grid? data fill? something else?

The second part of my question is what are the most **commonly used** methods of **creating and filling a table with data from an existing database**? Do people almost always just have to **hand code everything** or are there **great tools out there**?

**So far** I only found...igniteUI and I haven't actually read the website to see what it's about yet. I want to be able to design something... maybe using bootstrap or boilerplate.. and then create tables and fill them with tables. I've only ever made static sites. Anything that has some kind of GUI that lets me build these tables and and direct certain data types to specific table columns and rows would be a major plus, as I could compare what I just did with the code that was created... and then I could learn to make cleaned up handcoded versions myself. this is how I learned web design, I figured I could learn SOME parts of development the same way.

As I said above, the reason I am asking this question is because I do not know what any of the proper term(s) for what I'm describing and wasn't sure where to start.

Comment: There's not really a specific term. If your data is tabular data, you figure out how you retrieve tabular data from the database and then display it on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.. kind of a loaded question and somewhat opinionated, but I have 2 spare cents I can offer.

In the end, it depends what data you are trying to present, and what you want that user to do with that data.  With HTML, anyone can create a simple table and present some data (aka TR and TD tags).  What's this good for?  Showing tabular data.  What's this not good for?  Anything interactive...

OK, so then what do we use instead?  Again.. depends what you're trying to allow the user to use, AND if you have any existing resources in place.  For example, jqGrid is your front runner in late bound, jquery enabled sortable\editable data presentation.  ExtJS is also a popular scripting library, and they have some tools as well.

But that's late bound, javascript enabled stuff.. what about things that are already bundled into ASP.NET?  Well, you have the gridview and listview at your disposal.  Both are nice because they allow some quick and easy ways to connect to structured data, and if you're using some of the more popular data stores, such as SQL server, you even get drag\droppable connections (aka, less coding).  Telerik has been in the game a long time, and for some cash, you can get some pretty advanced tools.

Again, all opinionated stuff.  ASP.NET has some very nice things out of box, but nothing is perfect.. all of the items mentioned above I have used at one time or another, and they've been a great *foundation* for starting my applications.  But at the end of the day, I always had to take what was given to me and add\edit functionality to get what I ultimately needed.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This was just what I needed. I now know I need to watch some visual studio lessons...once I started discovering nifty things by accident in the IDE I realized that'd probably be a wise move...that is, learning vs basics before asp.net.  And it's going to be used to retrieve data from a relatively large copy of an ERP database. I want to use a large db that way I know automatically if the methods I choose are not optimized for large databases which is what I want to work with In the future.

Comment: Glad I could help.  www.asp.net has a lot of good content (Im sure you found it already).  Pluralsight is very, very good for both new and experienced developers alike.